# Como imprimir 5 datos duplicados de una tabla que tiene registros con mas de 20 SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero imprimir una serie de registros duplicados. Este es el query con el que obtengo mis resultados la ultima columna es la que se repite muchas veces en diferentes registros y tengo mas de 2000 registros con un Reporte_numero_carga_2 del 1 al 62 repetido mas menos 22 veces como puedo hacer para que solo me imprima 5 registros duplicados por cada Reporte_numero_carga2
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado final que busco es que fuera asi donde en vez de mostrarme todos los registros con un numero de carga igual solo me muestre 5 esto para tener mejor visibilidad de los datos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo sería el resultado que esperas para un dataset de muestra? Por favor, adjúntalo.

Comment: Buna tarde gracias por responder esta adjunto el resultado buscado.

Comment: Por favor, publica la consulta actual como texto, no como imagen. También, lo ideal es que publiques los datos como texto y no como imagenes. Finalmente, ¿Qué versión de mySQL utilizas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te propongo la siguiente solución:

```
set @n_max:=3;
set @n:=1;
set @grupo_previo=NULL;
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *,
      IF(grupo=@grupo_previo,@n:=@n+1,@n:=1) n,
      @grupo_previo:=grupo
      FROM pruebas
      ORDER BY grupo,id_prueba  
  ) c1 WHERE n<=@n_max;
```

Pata el dataset de pruebas:

```
CREATE TABLE pruebas(
  id_prueba int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  grupo varchar(1)
  );

INSERT INTO pruebas (grupo) VALUES
  ('A'),('A'),('A'),('A'),('A'),('A'),('A'),('A'),('A'),('A'),('A'),
  ('B'),('B'),('B'),('B'),('B'),
  ('C'),('C'),('C'),('C'),('C'),('C'),('C'),
  ('D'),('D');
```

Quedo a tu disposición para aclararte cualquier duda. Como es un poco idea feliz, cuando las ves, se entiende. Pero, para llegar a esa solución, hay que practicar un poco el uso de variables, el if, y hacer unas cuantas pruebas hasta que sale. Como ejercicio es muy completo, gracias por proponerlo.

Comment: Muchas Gracias quedo perfecto solo añadí mis condiciones y quedo exactamente como buscaba.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que en lo que planteas hay un problema no necesariamente tiene que haber un artículo repetido más de 5 veces. ¿Qué pasaría si solamente hubiesen 2 registros duplicados? A lo mejor ahora no te pasa, pero en un futuro podría sucederte y una aplicación tiene que estar preparada ante cualquier caso.

Te propongo una solución alternativa:

```
Select reporte_numero_carga2, count(reporte_numero_carga2) as total from TuTabla 
Groupby reporte_numero_carga2
```

Aquí lo que se hace es que se agrupa y solo aparece un registro y al lado una columna llamada total que pone la cantidad de veces que se repite ese dato en tu tabla que puede ser 1, 2, 5, 10, etc.

Me parece aquí así vas a tener más claridad.

Revisa este código y adáptalo a tu problema.

Comment: Hola. Edité tu respuesta para darle formato al código pubicado. Por favor, dale clic en el link de _editar_ para aprender cómo se hace. Un saludo.

Comment: Entiendo el punto y gracias por la respuesta mas que saber cuantos registros duplicados tengo lo que busco es imprimir solo n cantidad de registros repetidos si me salen 10 registros repetidos quisiera solo ver 4 por ejemplo y asi reducir la cantidad de registros en la consulta, necesito ver mas de un registro para comparar pero solo un par no los 10 duplicados.