# ¿Cómo mostrar los 5 productos más recientes de cada categoría en una sola consulta MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Deseo mostrar los 5 primeros productos mas recientes agregados de cada categoría.

En la misma tabla `tbl_products` tengo agregado una columna a la cual le he llamado `tags` la misma que va representado como una categoría: `zapatos`, `tazas`, `camisas`, `pantaloneta`, `calentador`.

Dadas a esas categoría que tiene cada producto registrado por ejemplo:

```
id_product product tags
   1        Pro1    camisas
   2        Pro2    zapatos
   3        Pro     pantaloneta
```

Quiero mostrar solo los primeros 5 productos más recientes pero de cada categoría diferente registrada en la misma tabla de la columna `tags`.

¿Cómo se tendría que preparar la consulta para mostrar los resultados deseados en una sola consulta?

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT
                            id_product,
                            product,
                            tags
                        FROM tbl_products WHERE active=? LIMIT 20");


while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    //Mostrar resultados deseados
}
```

Comment: Y como determinas cuáles registros son los más recientes?

Comment: @BetaM Se podría usar la expresión en la consulta `sql` de `ORDER BY id_product` para obtener los últimos productos agregados, ahora solo faltaría poder obtener solo los primeros 3 productos por cada categoría `tags`

Comment: Usas mysql o mariadb?

Comment: MyQSQLi es una clase de PHP para conectarte a bases de datos MySQL o MariaDB, por eso mi pregunta ¿cuál usas?

Comment: @BetaM MySQL amigo

Comment: Te comparto esta solución de la comunidad en inglés y por separado te propongo una respuesta mia https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23110673/get-latest-n-posts-for-each-user

Answer (score 1):

Curiosamente acabo de responder a una pregunta muy similar en:

[Como imprimir 5 datos duplicados de una tabla que tiene registros con mas de 20 SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/393444)

Adapto la respuesta a tu caso concreto:

```
set @n_max:=5;
set @n:=1;
set @tag_previa=NULL;
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *,
      IF(tags=@tag_previa,@n:=@n+1,@n:=1) n,
      @tag_previa:=tags
      FROM tbl_products
      ORDER BY tags,id_product  
  ) c1 WHERE n<=@n_max;
```

Donde, para ilustrarlo mejor, me he permitido ampliarte un poco el dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_products(
  id_product int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  product varchar(31),
  tags varchar(31)
  );

INSERT INTO tbl_products(product,tags) VALUES
  ('Pro1','camisas'),
  ('Pro2','zapatos'),
  ('Pro','pantaloneta'),
  ('','A'),('','A'),('','A'),('','A'),('','A'),('','A'),
  ('','A'),('','A'),('','A'),('','A'),('','A'),
  ('','B'),('','B'),('','B'),('','B'),('','B'),
  ('','C'),('','C'),('','C'),('','C'),('','C'),('','C'),('','C'),
  ('','D'),('','D');
```

Espero que sea lo que estabas buscando.

Respondiendo a tu comentario, incorporo cómo lanzar la consulta desde PHP:

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','__so');

$conn->query("
    set @n_max:=5;
");

$conn->query("
    set @n:=1;
");

$conn->query("
    set @tag_previa=NULL;
");

$r = $conn->query("
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT *,
          IF(tags=@tag_previa,@n:=@n+1,@n:=1) n,
          @tag_previa:=tags
          FROM tbl_products
          ORDER BY tags,id_product  
      ) c1 WHERE n<=@n_max;
")->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($r);
echo '</pre>';
```

Entiendo que no es necesario recurrir a una consulta preparada porque no estás aportando ningún dato externo. Un simple `query` debería ser suficiente.

Comment: amigo perdona la molestia, pero como agregó dicho ejemplo a la consulta preparada `$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT` ¿Como sería su ejecución para imprimir resultados en el bucle php?

Comment: @Valentina, atendiendo a tu comentario, amplío la respuesta. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes tomar en consideración el uso de [MariaDB 10.3.3](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group_concat/) para:

- Usar la función `GROUP_CONCAT` para concatenar en grupo todos los productos de cada tag
- Ordenamos de manera descendiente por medio del id (*como indicas en los comentarios*)
- Opcionalmente damos un separador de los elementos (*que inicialmente es una coma*), pero para fines de darle presentación de lista usamos un *salto de línea*
- Gracias a esta versión mencionada, podemos hacer uso de `LIMIT 5` dentro de la misma función anterior e indicar de esos productos ordenados de forma descendiente que solo queremos los primeros 5
- Damos un alias al listado generado en el punto anterior
- Agrupamos por la tag

Propuesta de consulta:

```
SELECT tags, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(product ORDER BY id_product DESC SEPARATOR '\n' LIMIT 5) AS Listado
FROM tbl_products
GROUP BY tags;
```

**Observaciones**

- La propuesta se hace en MariaDB por sus similitudes en cuanto a lo que usas actualmente
- La sintaxis mencionada en esta respuesta no parece estar soportada al momento en MySQL
- Al momento no es determinante para el ejercicio expuesto, pero:

  - No deberías almacenar las categorías por su nombre en la misma tabla de productos, ahí lo que debería existir por ejemplo es una tabla por separado que las guarde y esta misma se vincule con productos con una tabla intermedia, por que al menos yo veo que si es posible que un artículo o producto pertenezca a mas de una categoría.
  - Las tags son además identificadores en común para uno o n registros que comparten cierta relación de significado con estas, entonces yo creo que ahi categorías y las tags deberían ser conceptos separados

Comment: La propuesta del código indicado no esta soportado para MySQL ?

Comment: No, según lo que busqué el group concat en mysql no soporta el uso de limit, por eso quise proponer el uso de un software equivalente que es mariaDB o que apliques la solución que esta en el enlace que te dejé en los comentarios ahi indica como hacerlo en mysql